# Formula for the sum $\sum_{k=0}^a \frac{x^k}{k!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

How does one find a formula for the sum $\sum_{k=0}^a \frac{x^k}{k!}$ ? According to the post mentioned in the comments:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x^k}{k!}=\frac{ \Gamma (n+1,x)}{n!}e^x$$
...but how do you actually evaluate $\Gamma (n+1,x)$ for the positive integer n?

Comment: Are you certain that there is one?

Comment: $ \Gamma (s,x)=\int _{x}^{\infty }t^{s-1}\,\mathrm {e} ^{-t}\,{\rm {d}}t,\,\!$ $\Gamma (s+1,x)=s\Gamma (s,x)+x^{s}\mathrm {e} ^{-x}$ where $ \Gamma (s,x)$ is upper incomplete Gamma Function.